# HR Rep helping me left the company with no word

Tags: human-resources

I am unsure of how to progress on this matter:

Four weeks ago I initially interviewed with an HR representative for 30 minutes. I updated her one week later as a courtesy e-mail informing her I had to respond to (accept or decline) another position by January 5th. Two weeks ago, she informed me that I would hear about the status of my candidacy "in about a week or so"

Shortly after that, her LinkedIn page was updated, showing that she's now a recruiter at ANOTHER company. It says on her page that she left her previous employer in December and began her new job in December.

What are the general procedures when an HR representative leaves the company? Do they pass on candidates to another rep? Should I be trying to contact another recruiter from the company via LinkedIn? Will I seem creepy by doing this? I just can't believe the incompetence - she barely kept me informed.

Keep in mind, this is a really really good company - fortune 100 to say the least. I cannot lose this opportunity! Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I had to accept another position by January 5th."?? What other position? Is this relevant to the question? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @JanDoggen I think OP means that OP had another offer that they needed to accept or decline by that date, so needed to hear back from this company before then (or OP would, presumably, accept the certain offer).

Answer (score 14):

This should be simple to resolve.  Contact the company (By email or phone) and inform them of the situation and ask them who has been assigned to dealing with your case and if no one has who will be.

Answer (score -2):

You could contact the person through LinkedIn and ask for advice on how to proceed.  He or she should be able to give you the contact information for someone at the company who can help you.

Comment: -1. She now works at another company, why should her still perform tasks related to their previous job? You get job offers from companies, not from individuals, so it is up for the previous company to check the OP status. In fact, even if she is willing to help, she coulde be prevented from by law and/or NDA.

Comment: Can't hurt to ask.  Sometimes, people are just nice.